# avoiding returning an object from within an object

Tags: c#

I have an object that looks like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int UserID {get;set;}
    public List<SomeObjects> {get;set;}
    public List<SomeOtherObjects {get;set}
    public MyObject TheObjectForDB {get;set} //HERE: creating a new object

    public MyObject(int TheUserID)
    {
        this.UserID = TheUserID;
    }

    public LoadTheObjectFromDatabase()
    {
        MyQueries TheQueries = new MyQueries();
        TheObjectForDB = TheQueries.LoadFromDB(UserID) //HERE: object for DB work

        this.List<SomeObjects> = TheObjectForDB.List<SomeObjects>;
        this.List<SomeOtherObjects> = TheObjectForDB.List<SomeOtherObjects>;
    }
}
```

The database query essentially returns the same object type:

```
LoadFromDB = from...
             select new MyObject(TheUserID){...}
```

How can I remove this redundancy where I need to instantiate another object of the same type to populate the initial object?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `LoadTheObjectFromDatabase()` a `static` method which returns a new `MyObject`.

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int UserID {get;set;}
    public List<SomeObjects> {get;set;}
    public List<SomeOtherObjects {get;set}

    public MyObject(int TheUserID)
    {
        this.UserID = TheUserID;
    }

    public static MyObject LoadTheObjectFromDatabase(int userid)
    {
        MyQueries TheQueries = new MyQueries();
        MyObject TheObjectForDB = TheQueries.LoadFromDB(userid) //HERE: object for DB work

        return TheObjectForDB;
    }
}
```

Then, instead of doing `MyObject newObj = new MyObject(); newObj.LoadTheObjectFromDatabase();`, you'd just do `MyObject newObj = MyObject.LoadTheObjectFromDatabase();`

Comment: Any way around the static method, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @frenchie - There's certainly options, although this is the best way.  Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: I want to avoid creating two objects: 1 object that I instantiate to work with and 1 that I instantiate from within to do the database call.

Comment: @frenchie - That's why you make it static.  Then you only have one object.

Comment: @frenchie This would do exactly that.  The point is that you use the static method *instead of constructing the object explicitly*.  You could even make the constructor private (if you *always* populate it from the db).

Comment: @Bobson You'll need to make `UserID` a parameter of the static method.  As is, it's an instance field so the code won't compile.